# Java script redirect with header

Tags: javascript, php

Let me try and explain as best as I can,

I have the following code in my login.php:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
header("Location: home.php");
}
```

This ensures that if a user has logged in successfully, the url will always display mysite.com/home.php on all pages, this works fine for all php redirects using `href="another_page"`.

However this does not work for javascript redirects using `window.top.location.href="another_page"`, this instead redirects with the full url name (eg: mysite.com/java_redirected_page) instead of mysite.com/home.php. How can I get javascript redirects to work with headers as well, just like php does.

Answer (score 1):

use this - `window.location.href = 'home.php';` rather than `window.top.location.href = 'home.php';`

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is client side interpreter, it can't change headers from your server, while PHP generates responses from your web server, like Apache or nginx.

So the answer is that you can't change the way javascript redirects.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to have a nice result with your url, the only thing i can think of is MVC.

Never heard of it? Read this link http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mvc-for-noobs--net-10488

Its just a nice way to seperate your Backend from your Frontend and with that your redirects would work nicely.

Sad part about is, you would have to rethink yoru whole page, which is pretty timeconsuming because you would have to restructre everything.

Hope it helps